# Cakephp 3 - custom class for radio input label

Tags: css, templates, cakephp, radio-button, cakephp-3.x

I'm creating a multi-radio passing options as :

```
$this->Form->radio(
    'edu_tests_items.0.edu_sheets_items_grade_id',
     $eduSheetsGradesItems,
     ['autocomplete' => 'off']
);
```

The content of every `$eduSheetsGradesItems` is like :

```
(int) 0 => [
    'value' => (int) 1,
    'text' => 'Mal',
    'label' => [
        'class' => 'btn btn-danger'
    ],
    'class' => 'btn btn-danger'
],
```

Then I got this html for every radio button group ( here I show only the first label element )

```
<input name="edu_tests_items[0][edu_sheets_items_grade_id]" value="" type="hidden">
<label for="edu-tests-items-0-edu-sheets-items-grade-id-1">
    <input
        name="edu_tests_items[0][edu_sheets_items_grade_id]"
        value="1"
        class="btn btn-danger"
        id="edu-tests-items-0-edu-sheets-items-grade-id-1"
        autocomplete="off"
        type="radio">
    Mal
</label>
```

What I'm trying to do is to set a specific class ( different for every radio button label ) for the label element ( `btn btn-danger` in the example ) but I cannot figure out how.

Answer (score 2):

The radio widget doesn't support individual radio label configuration, it only supports configuration for all labels ([current not properly documented in the Cookbook](https://github.com/cakephp/docs/pull/5538)), which can be passed via the `radio()` methods third argument, like:

```
$this->Form->radio(
    'edu_tests_items.0.edu_sheets_items_grade_id',
    $eduSheetsGradesItems,
    [
        'autocomplete' => 'off',
        'label' => [
            'class' => 'btn btn-danger'
        ]
    ]
);
```

You could configure this via templates too, which would however only work using the `FormHelper::control/input()` method, but you don't really have to.

So if you want to apply the same class to all labels, then the above will do it. If you need to apply different classes do different labels, then you'll have to go with a custom widget, and for example extend the `Cake\View\Widget\RadioWidget` and override the `RadioWidget::_renderLabel()` method to support possible `label` keys in the `$radio` argument, which maps to your individual option-set.

Here's a quick & dirty example:

```
protected function _renderLabel($radio, $label, $input, $context, $escape)
{
    if ($label &&
        isset($radio['label'])
    ) {
        $label = is_array($label) ? $label : [];

        if (isset($label['class'])) {
            $radio['label'] = $this->_templates->addClass($radio['label'], $label['class']);
        }

        $label = $radio['label'] + $label;
    }

    return parent::_renderLabel($radio, $label, $input, $context, $escape);
}
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Views > Helpers > Form > Creating Radio Buttons](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-radio-buttons)**
- **[API > \Vake\View\Helper\FormHelper::radio()](https://api.cakephp.org/3.5/class-Cake.View.Helper.FormHelper.html#_radio)**
- **[Cookbook > Views > Helpers > Form > Adding Custom Widgets](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#adding-custom-widgets)**

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I'll go the custom widget way.